# Conditional INSERT or UPDATE in SQLITE

Tags: ios, sqlite

Please Advice a little bit about INSERT or UPDATE in SQLITE

I'm using this code 
  `NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO downloadedBook(bookID, courseID, bookName, bookPath, bookVersion, pageAmount, price, episode) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", %f, %d,%f, \"%@\")",bookID,courseID,bookName,bookPath,bookVersion,pageAmount,price,episode];`

for insert,

and this code

`NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE downloadedBook SET bookID = \"%@\",courseID = \"%@\", bookName = \"%@\", bookPath = \"%@\", bookVersion = %f, pageAmount = %d, price = %f,episode = \"%@\" WHERE bookID = \"%@\"" , bookID,courseID,bookName,bookPath,bookVersion, pageAmount, price, episode,bookID];`

for update.

It works fine.Now, how can I use `if` conditions while performing these operations? For example I would like to check  "if I have this, data will update" Please Advice.

How can I do this Please Guide me.

Comment: The first advice would be to use "prepared statements" to protect against SQL injection: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the table has some unique constraint, such as `bookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.
2. Use `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ...` with the insert syntax you have. If the insert would result in a constraint violation (e.g. `bookID` already exists), the conflicting rows are first removed and the data is then inserted.

Also consider using prepared statements and `?` placeholders for the literals to prevent SQL syntax problems and injection attacks, and to improve performance.

Comment: Big Thanks I'm wrong with myself about `bookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` Thanks teacher @laalto